# git clone from gitlab - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: git, github, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I try to clone a git repo (from gitlab) with HTTP but it gives me the following error:

```
$ git clone http://gitlab.XXX....git                          
Cloning into 'XXX'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 241, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (241/241), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (113/113), done.
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Any solution for that, please?

Note that the repo is large (it contains 3.3GB of resources).

Thank you so much!

Comment: were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score -2):

it's due to low connectivity of your internet. Try to change into different network or check your internet connection

Answer (score -3):

I came across this issue while installing Homebrew on macOS. I entered the following commands on the Terminal and it worked for me.

Run uninstall script:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Set Git Compression:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Set Git buffer size:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

Run installation script:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```